# React native with socket.io socket creates but it always on reconnect

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I'm using "react-native": "0.60.4" and "socket.io-client": "2.1.1". I create socket connect as below, socket creates but it always on reconnect.

When I use

```
XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ?
    GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest :
    GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;
```

in my project, it connects, but nothing works.

This is the socket code

```
let socket = io('http://192.168.0.6:8090', {
    transport: ['websocket'],
    jsonp: false 
});

console.log(socket);

socket.on('reconnecting', (attemptNumber) => {
    console.log(attemptNumber + " reconnecting... ")
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, finally after 3 days struggling with this, I found the bug, 
looks like in react native is "transports" not "transport"